# How to start Playwright browser in jest from setupFilesAfterEnv hook, so it will be acessible inside test file, using TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, playwright, babel-jest

In Jest I want to launch browser from `setupFilesAfterEnv` not to repeat this step in evey test file, using Jest and Playwright. Despite browser launching, and global variables accessible for test, I get error: `TypeError: global.browser.newContext is not a function'. I'm using Babel to use TS in Jest

## My setup

### jest.config.cjs

```
const config = {
    testTimeout: 20000,
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/setup.ts"]
};

module.exports = config;
```

### setup.ts

```
import {chromium} from "playwright-chromium";

global.browser = chromium.launch({headless: false});
global.my_val = "10"
```

### test.test.ts

```
describe("Test", () => {
    let context;
    let page;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        console.log("Global 10")
        console.log(global.my_val)
        context = await global.browser.newContext();
        page = await context.newPage();
    })

    test(...)
```

Browser is starting properly, as I can see it in list of processes (it does not start in GUI mode, despite headless:false).

`console.log(global.my_val)` is properly printing 10, so global variables from setup are seen in this context.

But this error prevents me from doing anything:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'newContext')

      28 |
      29 |     beforeEach(async () => {
    > 30 |         context = await global.browser.newContext();
         |                                        ^
      31 |         page = await context.newPage();
      32 |     })
      33 |
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, seems it is only possible with `testEnvironment` in JS. Possible with TS if using TS-node

Solution:

```
const { chromium } = require('playwright-chromium');
const NodeEnvironment = require('jest-environment-node').TestEnvironment;


class CustomEnvironment extends NodeEnvironment {
    constructor(config, context) {
        super(config, context);
    }

    async setup() {
        await super.setup();
        this.global.browser = await chromium.launch({headless: false});
    }

    async teardown() {
        await super.teardown();
        await this.global.browser.close();
    }

}

module.exports = CustomEnvironment;
```